# splitting csv file in individual columns based on range of values in python

Tags: python, csv

I would like to split/separate values given within a range for a csv column, add new data for each number within the range while keeping the data from all other columns to match.

It is important that I am able to maintain the data from the other columns (Job ID) for any numbers within the range of (x-y), so my resultant csv being written to is obviously going to be much longer than the original.

I would like my output csv to represent individual columns for each number in the range of 26-29, 66-67 etc. So I would like an output csv file where for example:

Job ID 21879 is represented 4 times, each for 26,27,28 and 29.

I would like to do this as a first step before the following steps written for my script but am getting stuck at this point.

The rest of the script splits the Date values by (/), assigns these to new rows and concatenates them with the page number field. It is the page number field I am looking to split for the number in the displayed range.

The resultant list I have for this script only outputs the required values from the Job ID column, along with a concatenated date and page field in the second. This section works fine, it is the last csv file I need to represent each number as an individual number for a given range.

Appreciate the help with splitting these range of values and maintaining the other data fields.

A subset of my input data is as follows:

```
Job ID  Job summary Link    Locality    Received    Job status  Asset   Date       Page No
21879   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 15/06/2018  Completed   Water   28/06/2018  26-29
21878   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 28/06/2018  Completed   Water       
21877   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 28/06/2018  Completed   Water       
21876   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 28/06/2018  Completed   Water       
21875   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 28/06/2018  Completed   Water       
21874   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 28/06/2018  Completed   Water   26/07/2018  42-43
21873   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 27/06/2018  Completed   Water   26/07/2018  
21872   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 27/06/2018  Completed   Water   26/07/2018  66-67
21871   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 27/06/2018  Completed   Water   26/07/2018  07-08
21870   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 27/06/2018  Completed   Water   28/06/2018  59
21869   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 27/06/2018  Completed   Water   28/06/2018  58
21868   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 26/06/2018  Completed   Water       
21867   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 26/06/2018  Completed   Water
```

What I would like as an output is:

```
Job ID  Job summary Link    Locality    Received    Job status  Asset   Date       Page No
21879   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 15/06/2018  Completed   Water   28/06/2018  26
21879   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 15/06/2018  Completed   Water   28/06/2018  27  
21879   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 15/06/2018  Completed   Water   28/06/2018  28  
21879   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 15/06/2018  Completed   Water   28/06/2018  29  
21878   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 28/06/2018  Completed   Water       
21877   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 28/06/2018  Completed   Water       
21876   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 28/06/2018  Completed   Water       
21875   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 28/06/2018  Completed   Water       
21874   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 28/06/2018  Completed   Water   26/07/2018  42
21874   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 28/06/2018  Completed   Water   26/07/2018  43
21873   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 27/06/2018  Completed   Water   26/07/2018  
21872   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 27/06/2018  Completed   Water   26/07/2018  66
21872   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 27/06/2018  Completed   Water   26/07/2018  67
21871   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 27/06/2018  Completed   Water   26/07/2018  07
21871   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 27/06/2018  Completed   Water   26/07/2018  08
21870   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 27/06/2018  Completed   Water   28/06/2018  59
21869   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 27/06/2018  Completed   Water   28/06/2018  58
21868   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 26/06/2018  Completed   Water       
21867   Addition    Documents Link  CBD 26/06/2018  Completed   Water
```

Current script is:

```
import os
import csv
with open('CSV_File.csv','r') as csvinput:  
    with open('temp__spreadsheet_cache_1.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
        for row in csv.reader(csvinput):
            if row[7] == "Date":
                writer.writerow(row+["day"])
            else:
                writer.writerow(row+row[4].split('/'))
with open('temp__spreadsheet_cache_1.csv','r') as csvinput:
    with open('temp__spreadsheet_cache_2.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
        for row in csv.reader(csvinput):
            if row[7] == "Date":
                writer.writerow(row+["month"])
            else:
                writer.writerow(row+row[4].split('/'))
with open('temp__spreadsheet_cache_2.csv','r') as csvinput:
    with open('temp__spreadsheet_cache_3.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
        for row in csv.reader(csvinput):
            if row[7] == "Date":
                writer.writerow(row+["year"])
            else:
                writer.writerow(row+row[4].split('/'))
with open('temp__spreadsheet_cache_3.csv','r') as csvinput:
    with open('temp__spreadsheet_cache_4.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
        for row in csv.reader(csvinput):
            if row[7] == "Date":
                writer.writerow(row+["Concatenation"])
            else:
                writer.writerow(row+row[4].split('/'))
#---Using Current output (temp__spreadsheet_cache_4.csv) to create new list--
blank =[]
with open (r'temp__spreadsheet_cache_4.csv', 'r') as NEW_CSV:
    csvReader = csv.reader(NEW_CSV, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    header = csvReader.next()
    JobIndex = header.index("Job ID")
    PageIndex = header.index("Page No")
    DayIndex = header.index("day")
    MonthIndex = header.index("month")
    YearIndex = header.index("year")
    Summary = header.index("Job summary")
    StatusIndex = header.index("Job status")
    class_1 = header.index("Asset")
    for row in csvReader:
        Page = row[PageIndex]
        Day = row[DayIndex]
        Month = row[MonthIndex]
        Year = row[YearIndex]
        JobID = row[JobIndex]
        To_be_overridden_concat = row[PageIndex]
        Type = row[Summary]
        Status = row[StatusIndex]
        waterclass = row[class_1]
        if waterclass == 'Water'  
          blank.append([JobID,Day,Month,Year,Page,To_be_overridden_concat])
str(blank)
for column in blank:
    column[1] = column[1].lstrip('0')
    column[2] = column[2].lstrip('0')
    column[3] = column[3].lstrip('0')
    column[4] = column[4].lstrip('0')
for column in blank:
    column[0] = column[0].lstrip()
    column[1] = column[1].lstrip()
    column[2] = column[2].lstrip()
    column[3] = column[3].lstrip() 
    column[4] = column[4].lstrip()
for column in blank:
    column[0] = column[0].rstrip()
    column[1] = column[1].rstrip()
    column[2] = column[2].rstrip()
    column[3] = column[3].rstrip()
    column[4] = column[4].rstrip()
    column[5] = column[1]+column[2]+column[3]+column[4]
##os.remove("temp__spreadsheet_cache_4.csv")
os.remove("temp__spreadsheet_cache_3.csv")
os.remove("temp__spreadsheet_cache_2.csv")
os.remove("temp__spreadsheet_cache_1.csv")
for row in blank:
    del row[1:5]
print blank[0:10]
```

Comment: Could you please share the _real_ content/structure of your input? The fact the you create your csv reader without specifying a delimiter somewhat indicates your input has commas as separator instead of whitespace characters as suggested by your example above. Specifically, I'd like to know if there is blank cells when no Date and Page No are given, i.e. the line has two trailing commas.

Comment: Also, your desired example output looks structurally identical to your input, except for the duplicated rows, but your code would ignore a number of original columns while adding some new ones. So, which of the two is your desired output? Also also ... :) the line `if waterclass == 'Water'` is missing a colon in the end and leads me to the question: Do you want this done only if `Asset` is `Water` in your input?

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to the forum. Apparently have to post a certain number of times for adding images/screenshots of data, but delimiter is on line 38. Without adding a screenshot I'm a little unsure of how to do it. So tried to adjust only for a visual data representation from a csv file. The excel data has just been copied to a .py file here. Blank cells are okay and not having an issue with these. The part I'm stuck on would actually be before the code provided, just trying to give context by adding what's been done so far. Correct! Error in copying, should be....'Water': Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the provided code has no direct relation to your question, better don't post it. It will only confuse people as it confused me. You should only include whatever is necessary to understand and answer your question. Have you made any attempt to get from your example input to your example output yet?

Comment: A direct copy/paste of your sample data (from a text editor) would be better than trying to format it for the question. Use the [edit] button to make any changes to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I need to assume that you have a standard CSV file with commas separating the fields, such as:

```
Job ID,Job summary,Link,Locality,Received,Job status,Asset,Date,Page No
21879,Addition,Documents,Link,CBD,15/06/2018,Completed,Water,28/06/2018,26-29
21878,Addition,Documents,Link,CBD,28/06/2018,Completed,Water,,
21874,Addition,Documents,Link,CBD,28/06/2018,Completed,Water,26/07/2018,42-43
21873,Addition,Documents,Link,CBD,27/06/2018,Completed,Water,26/07/2018,1
```

If this is the case then your data could to fixed as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv

fieldnames = ["Job ID", "Job summary", "Link", "Locality", "ReceivedDay", "ReceivedMonth", "ReceivedYear", "Job status", "Asset", "Day", "Month", "Year", "Page No"]

with open("CSV_File.csv", "rb") as f_input, open("output.csv", "wb") as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    next(csv_input) # skip the header

    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(fieldnames)

    for row in csv_input:
        date_received = row[5].split('/')

        if len(row[8]):
            date = row[8].split('/')
        else:
            date = ["", "", ""]

        if row[9].find('-') != -1:
            pages = map(int, row[9].split("-"))

            for page in range(pages[0], pages[1] + 1):
                output_row = row[:5] +  date_received + row[6:8] + date + [page]
                csv_output.writerow(output_row)
        else:
            output_row = row[:5] +  date_received + row[6:8] + date + [row[9]]
            csv_output.writerow(output_row)
```

This would give you an output file starting:

```
Job ID,Job summary,Link,Locality,ReceivedDay,ReceivedMonth,ReceivedYear,Job status,Asset,Day,Month,Year,Page No
21879,Addition,Documents,Link,CBD,15,06,2018,Completed,Water,28,06,2018,26
21879,Addition,Documents,Link,CBD,15,06,2018,Completed,Water,28,06,2018,27
21879,Addition,Documents,Link,CBD,15,06,2018,Completed,Water,28,06,2018,28
21879,Addition,Documents,Link,CBD,15,06,2018,Completed,Water,28,06,2018,29
21878,Addition,Documents,Link,CBD,28,06,2018,Completed,Water,,,,
21877,Addition,Documents,Link,CBD,28,06,2018,Completed,Water,,,,
21876,Addition,Documents,Link,CBD,28,06,2018,Completed,Water,,,,
21875,Addition,Documents,Link,CBD,28,06,2018,Completed,Water,,,,
21874,Addition,Documents,Link,CBD,28,06,2018,Completed,Water,26,07,2018,42
21874,Addition,Documents,Link,CBD,28,06,2018,Completed,Water,26,07,2018,43
```

It works by first skiping the input header and writing a suitable output header. It assumes the date received is always present. `split('/')` is used to break the dates into three parts. If the page number contains a `-` symbol, `split('-')` is used to get the two parts, it is then converted to two integers.

The output row is created by combining together parts of the input row with the two date parts.